# Bootstrap 4 search box that render search results on a website

Tags: bootstrap-4, search-box

I have been designing a website using bootstrap4 on visual code, but I am having problems creating a search box that will render results when someone types in something in the search box and clicks search.

Would be glad to know the code to write down for it.

I was able to design the search box, but I don't know how to make it operational, meaning, when i type in something in the search box and click the search link, nothing comes up, no search results, no other page pops up or no page results pops up.

Comment: Hi @Stephane, in order to help, people are going to need to see what code you are trying so they can help you edit it. Thanks if you can edit your post to include all that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.